# Unable to upload package in AEM 6.2 - package file parameter missing

Tags: aem, crx

Everytime I upload a package on my QA server via Package Manager, it keeps loading it for a long time and then throws an error saying "package file parameter missing"

The error logs show absolutely no activity regarding the package.

This happens for both code packages (/apps/...) and content packages (/content/...)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your server has a tmp (linux) or temp (windows) folder accessible to the AEM process with full permission. This error occurs when the aem process cannot find the temp folder which it uses to temporarily store packages when they are being uploaded.